# JavaFX program runs, but still getting exception

Tags: java, javafx, bigdecimal

I'm writing a JavaFX program that calculates a tip using a slider. It's works fairly well, but when I change the value of the slider, I get a slew of errors such as `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Label.text : A bound value cannot be set.`

It seems that my error has something to do with binding to the slider, but not sure what is the problem since it runs how I was expecting. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is the program:

TipCalculator.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TipCalculator extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TipCalculator.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Tip Calculator");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

TipCalculatorController.java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TipCalculatorController
{
    private static final NumberFormat currency =
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private static final NumberFormat percent =
        NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

    private BigDecimal tipPercentage = new BigDecimal(0.15);

    @FXML
    private TextField amountTextField;

    @FXML
    private Label tipPercentageLabel;

    @FXML 
    private Slider tipPercentageSlider;

    @FXML
    private TextField tipTextField;

    @FXML
    private TextField totalTextField;

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(amountTextField.getText());
            BigDecimal tip = amount.multiply(tipPercentage);
            BigDecimal total = amount.add(tip);

            tipTextField.setText(currency.format(tip));
            totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            amountTextField.setText("Enter amount");
            amountTextField.selectAll();
            amountTextField.requestFocus();
        }

        tipPercentageLabel.textProperty().bind           
            (tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().asString("%.0f"));

        currency.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Number>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                        Number oldValue, Number newValue)
                {
                    tipPercentage =
                            BigDecimal.valueOf(newValue.intValue() / 100.0);
                    tipPercentageLabel.setText(percent.format(tipPercentage));
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

TipCalculator.fxml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane hgap="8.0" vgap="8.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TipCalculatorController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="Amount" />
      <Label fx:id="tipPercentageLabel" text="15%" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label text="Tip" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label text="Total" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <TextField fx:id="amountTextField" onAction="#initialize" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="tipTextField" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="totalTextField" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Slider fx:id="tipPercentageSlider" blockIncrement="5.0" max="30.0" onDragDetected="#initialize" value="15.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="14.0" left="14.0" right="14.0" top="14.0" />
   </padding>
</GridPane>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the exception says, a bound value cannot be set. The point of a binding is that you declare that one property should always have a value that depends on another property. If you could then set the bound property directly, you would be able to violate the contract you specify by the binding.

So when you do

```
tipPercentageLabel.textProperty().bind           
        (tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().asString("%.0f"));
```

you ensure that the text property of `tipPercentageLabel` will *always* have the string value of `tipPercentageSlider.getValue()` (formatted with one decimal, etc). If you were then allowed to set the text of `tipPercentageLabel`, you could violate this binding, so this is now prohibited.

Consequently,

```
    tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<Number>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue)
            {
                tipPercentage =
                        BigDecimal.valueOf(newValue.intValue() / 100.0);
                tipPercentageLabel.setText(percent.format(tipPercentage));
            }
        }
    );
```

throws an exception when the slider value changes, because it tries to explicitly set the text of the label.

The binding and the listener are actually just two ways of achieving (more or less) the same thing (give or take some formatting). So the solution to the issue is that you should have only one of these: either remove the binding, or remove the listener. Personally, I find the binding approach more elegant (I prefer the explicit declaration of the dependency, whereas the listener is more mechanistic). Your mileage may vary.

If you want to use the percent format, you can do that with a binding with

```
tipPercentageLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    tipPercentage = BigDecimal.valueOf(newValue.intValue() / 100.0);
    return percent.format(tipPercentage);
}, tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty());
```

or you can just do

```
tipPercentageLabel.textProperty().bind(tipPercentageSlider.asString("%.0f%%"));
```

(`%%` in a format string gives a `"%"` sign).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I was trying to explicitly set the tipPercentageLabel. I ended up deleting the last line of  code: `tipPercentageLabel.setText(percent.format(tipPercentage));` and all of my errors are gone. Thanks!

Comment: @greglorious_85 But now the listener isn't actually doing anything, so you may as well delete it entirely.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm not sure how to implement it though. I tried plugging in the code you suggested, but I couldn't get it to run.

Comment: @greglorious_85 All I'm saying is you can delete the listener entirely. The rest is just showing you ways to include a `%` sign in the text using the binding (which is what you appear to be trying to do in the listener).

Comment: But I need the listener! The point of this exercise is to actually have a listener

Comment: @greglorious_85 Why do you need a listener? Once you have removed the call to `setText(...)`, your listener isn't doing anything.  (In fact, it isn't doing anything anyway, except throwing a bunch of exceptions.) The binding already does it all for you.

Comment: It's an exercise to reimplement an existing app to get rid of a button. Here are the instructions: The Tip Calculator app from Section 12.5 does not need a Button to perform its calculations. Reimplement this app to use property listeners to perform the calculations whenever the user modifies the bill amount or changes the custom tip percentage. Also use a property binding to update the Label that displays the tip percentage.

Comment: Not exactly homework, but it is from a textbook. I'm trying it out on my own

Comment: So why not use the binding to update the tip percentage, and a listener to update the total, if you want to learn both ways of doing this? It doesn't look like you are currently updating the total...

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, just trying to figure out how to do it really. This is my first foray into javafx and I've never done binding before.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107 (which is one of the better parts of the official tutorial).

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, you definitely helped me with the errors I was receiving. I’m still not entirely sure why you are saying my listener isn’t doing anything because it is updating my tip and total, albeit not instantaneously like the binding, but I think it will do for now.

Comment: @greglorious_85 I mean it is not doing anything to the UI. It's not updating the label, because trying to do that just throws an exception. You should update the total text field there too, maybe that is your intention?

Comment: If the listener is not updating the labels, then what is? Sorry, I’m a bit confused.

Comment: @greglorious_85 The binding is updating the label.

Comment: So how would I write it using both a binding and listener?

Comment: @greglorious_85 The listener should update the "total" text field, not the label. You can't update the label if it's bound, that's the very first thing I said in the answer.

Comment: I'm at my wits end here. If you don't want to, that's fine, but can you tell me how to write this last part? I'm trying to write something along the lines of: `tipPercentage =
                            BigDecimal.valueOf(newValue.intValue() / 100.0);
                    totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));` but it won't let me do this, and I have no idea why.